# Fourier transform of PDF of t-distribution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Can you all please solve this one?

I was originally thining of
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iax}\left(\frac{x^2}{n} + 1\right)^{-\frac12(n+1)} \,dx.$$

My mentor has told me that if n is odd you can calculate this and if n is even you will get to use special functions.

If n is odd.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iax}\left(\frac{x^2}{2k+1} + 1\right)^{-(k+1)} \,dx.$$
This case is done by Shashi by employing contour integration. Thanks.

If n is even
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iax}\left(\frac{x^2}{2k} + 1\right)^{-\frac12(2k+1)} \,dx.$$
This is unsolved yet.
\begin{align}
I=(2k)^\frac{k+1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-iax}}{(x^2+2k)^\frac{k+1}{2}}\,dx
\end{align}

So it is enough to do the integral
 \begin{align}
J = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{e^{-iax}}{(x^2+2k)^\frac{k+1}{2}}\,dx
\end{align}
where b > $0$.
Consider the contour integral:

\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^\frac{k+1}{2}}\,dz
\end{align}

Shashi gives me an advice: since the exponent of the denominator of the first integral I have written is not an integer in the even case. One must then be careful with the branch cut and all that.
So this is a problem of contour integral having branch cuts.
But I don't know how to choose a proper contour for that...

Comment: You know that this will lead to special functions, right?  Are you ready for that?

Comment: I edited this to hopefully reflect the function that you actually meant.

Comment: Hey Shashi. I heard from my Mentor that  you can calculate it but I don’t know how..

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks, Cameron!

Comment: @Schauder I didn't say you cannot calculate it. Moreover you just specified that the degrees of freedom is integer valued. I think in that case we have hope for a nice closed form.

Comment: A hint for further googling : "Fourier  Transform of PDF" is classicaly called "characteristic function". See formulas (16)-(20) of (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentst-Distribution.html) with - indeed - a distinction between odd and even cases.

Comment: @JeanMarie I learned in mathematical statistics class that Fourier transform of PDF is characteristic function...Anyway, I can’t solve it by myself.

Comment: One way to do this is to use the Schwinger trick $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{a^n}=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-at}dt $ to make the $x$ integral Gaussian after a switch of integration order. The $t$ integral left after that's done can be massaged into one of the integral forms for Bessel K.

Comment: The Bessel K is the general answer and encompasses even nonintegral degrees of freedom, it's just that sometimes (in your odd cases) the Bessel K takes the form of a polynomial times an exponential.

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know if one would call this a closed form, but it gives a finite sum with $k$ terms. Okay, let's give it a try.*

We assume $a\geq 0$. Rewriting the integral first.
\begin{align}
I=(2k+1)^{k+1}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-iax}}{(x^2+2k+1)^{k+1}}\,dx
\end{align}
So, it is enough to do the integral $$J=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{-iax}}{(x^2+b)^{k+1}}\,dx$$ where $b>0$. 
Okay, consider the contour integral:
\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^{k+1}}\,dz
\end{align}
where $C=C(R)$ is the famous semi-circle contour in the lower half plane with radius $R$ large enough so that the pole is inclosed. It is clear by Jordan's Lemma that the contribution of the circular part of the contour goes to zero as $R\to\infty$. Hence we have:
\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{C(R)} \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^{k+1}}\,dz =J
\end{align}
By the Residue Theorem one has:
\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{C(R)} \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^{k+1}}\,dz = -2\pi i \text{Res}_{z=-i\sqrt[]{b}} \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^{k+1}}
\end{align}
Before doing the residue, define:
\begin{align}
f(z):=e^{-iaz},\ \ \ \ \ g(z):=(z-i\sqrt[]{b})^{-k-1}
\end{align} 
Now the residue is:
\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{z=-i\sqrt[]{b}} \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^{k+1}}&= \lim_{z\to -i\sqrt[]{b}} \frac{1}{k!}\left[ \frac{d^k}{dz^k}\frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z-i\sqrt[]{b})^{k+1}}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}f^{(k-j)}(-i\sqrt[]{b})g^{(j)}(-i\sqrt[]{b})
\end{align}
Where we have used the [Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule). Let us find the values  of the derivatives of $f$:
\begin{align}
f^{(k-j)}(-i\sqrt[]{b})=(-ia)^{k-j}\exp(-a\sqrt[]{b})
\end{align}
and the ones of $g$:
\begin{align}
g^{(j)}(-i\sqrt[]{b}) = (-1)^j\frac{(k+j)!}{k!(-2i\sqrt[]{b})^{k+j+1}}
\end{align}
So:
\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{z=-i\sqrt[]{b}} \frac{e^{-iaz}}{(z^2+b)^{k+1}}&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-ia)^{k-j}\exp(-a\sqrt[]{b})(-1)^j\frac{(k+j)!}{k!(-2i\sqrt[]{b})^{k+j+1}}\\
&=ie^{-a\sqrt[]{b}}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k-j}\frac{(k+j)!}{k!^2(2\sqrt[]{b})^{k+j+1}}
\end{align}
Substituting $b=2k+1$ we finally get after simplifying things:

> \begin{align}
> I&=
> \pi e^{-a\sqrt[]{2k+1}}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+j}{j}\frac{a^{k-j}} {(k-j)!2^{k+j}} \sqrt[]{2k+1}^{k+1-j}
> \end{align}

Surely one can do something similar for $a<0$..

Comment: Thanks so much Shashi! I really appreciate it. The even case can be done by the same way, do you think?

Comment: @Schauder I don't think so since the exponent of the denominator of the first integral I have written is not an integer in the even case. One must then be careful with the branch cut and all that.

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean! If n is even the integral is rewrote as I = (2k)^((1/2)(2k+1))∫[-∞,∞] e(-iax)/{(x^2 + 2k)^((1/2)(2k+1). So this will be a problem of contour Integration having branch cut..

Comment: @Schauder I think the answer now is somehow simplified.

Comment: Thanks! by the way, I cannot calculate the second one...